# Spatial navigation

Tags: javascript, dom

i want to create navigation on elements that got tabindex and by pressing key up I want to get index of that element, pass it to counter and set next element to be active. The problem is that I can't get the index of element which is focused. Code:

```
var focusable = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[tabindex]'));
focusable[1].focus()
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  var counter;
  if (e.keyCode == '38') {
    //here i want to pass the index of elment 
    //from array which is focused and pass it to counter
    console.log('up');
    counter++
    console.log(counter)
    focusable[counter].focus()
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `querySelectorAll("[tabindex]")` won't return any elements unless they specifically have the `tabindex` attribute set on them (it's not enough that the attribute *could* be used on the element), but if you do populate the array, then how about something like this:

```js
// Make sure all the intended elements are placed into the array:
var focusable = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input, select, textarea, button'));
console.log(focusable);  // Test

// First item is item 0, not 1
focusable[0].focus()

// This needs to be outside the event handler or it will get reset every time a key is pressed
var counter = 0;

window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {

  if (e.keyCode == '38') {    
    // Can't let counter get higher than max index
    counter = (counter === focusable.length -1) ? 0 : ++counter;
    
    focusable[counter].focus();  // set focus to next item in the array
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text">
<select>
  <option>test</option>
</select>
<textarea></textarea>
<button>test</button>
```